# How to get isLoading from React Query custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am trying to get isLoading returned from a custom React Query hook.

Here is my hook:

```
async function getUserDiscussions(
  user: User | null
): Promise<Post[] | null> {
  const { data } = await axiosInstance.get(
    `/getUserPosts`,
  );
  return data;
}

export function usePosts(): Post[] {

  const fallback: Post[] = [];
  const { data: posts = fallback } = useQuery(
    [
      queryKeys.posts,
    ],
    () => getUserDiscussions(user),
  );
  return posts;
}
```

I am then calling the hook in a component like this:

```
const posts = usePosts()
```

I would like to then be able to access isLoading and update the UI accordingly.

How can I access `isLoading` from the query in the custom hook and use it in the component?

Comment: Just return the query itself and you can access it's methods!

Comment: Thanks @VahidAlimohamadi, can you give me an example of how I can do that please?

Comment: The first answer is showing how @sgrmhdk returning the ```isLoading``` method. Also you can return the whole query obj. ```return useQuery(...)``` instead of ```posts``` and ```isLoading```.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from useQuery and return the same from your function.

```
export function usePosts(): Post[] {

  const fallback: Post[] = [];
  const { data: posts = fallback, isLoading } = useQuery(
    [
      queryKeys.posts,
    ],
    () => getUserDiscussions(user),
  );
  return {posts,isLoading};
}
```

Comment: https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/reference/useQuery?from=reactQueryV3&original=https%3A%2F%2Freact-query-v3.tanstack.com%2Freference%2FuseQuery You can refer documentation here.

Comment: it seems there must be a type error because of you determined the function return type as an array.

Comment: Hi @VahidAlimohamadi, Yes it won't let me return posts as it isn't defined on the types.